# How does race day work?

Tags: pc, need-for-speed-prostreet

I dominated the 'battle machine' race day but I can't figure out what to do next to proceed. The next level is locked.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: (Can I insert screenshots here?)

Comment: Yes, you can add screenshots by clicking the image icon above the text when you edit your post. You can upload a picture from your PC or from a website link there. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to the small events before going to the big events. Small events are events that opens after you unlock the big events (such as the skull icon on top of the BATTLE MACHINE or the weird circle thing below the BATTLE MACHINE, you need to play several events like that in order to unlock the next big event)